# Unable to push values into list

Tags: javascript

I am unable to push any elements into an array using `.push()`. The code here is my attempt:

```
text = "fihdfhdkfhkdsfkjd";

var myName = "Anthony Pham";
var hits = [];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i+++) {
    if (text[i] === myName[i]) {
        for(var j = i; j <= (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using CodeAcedmy and is givng me an error that my second `for` loop is unable to push any values into `hits`. I have tried switching between `myName[j]` and `text[j]` in the `hits.push()` but still cannot make the program work right. What is wrong with my second `for` loop here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ..

```
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === myName[i]) {
        for(var j = i; j <= (myName.length + i); j++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the extra + in `i+++`, you have a logic problem.  The only time `text[i] === myName[i]` would be true is when `i` equals 9 (the h in Pham).  Then you have this loop:

```
for (var j = i; j <= (myName.length + i); j++) {
    // j = i = 9
    // j <= 12 + 9 = 21
    hits.push(text[j]);
    // hits = [h, a, m, undefined, undefined, undefined, ... , undefined ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use charAt(), not array brackets.

Also, you're never checking the bounds on myName, and are reading past the end in both places it's referenced.

Comment: What do you mean use `charAt()`?

Comment: when selecting a character out of a string, the square bracket notation is not a universal standard.  Instead of text[i] === myName[i], it would be text.charAt(i) === myName.charAt(i)